# DropDown list [asp.net core 2.0]

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

Hi im having problem with my view

as you can see there is an input and a select option

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="DomWasLoc" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="DomWasLoc" class="form-control" id="firstname" name="firstname" />
    <select class="form-control"
        id="name" name="name"
        asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.LocationList, "LocName","LocName"))">
        <option value="">- Select -</option>
    </select>
    <span asp-validation-for="DomWasLoc" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

every time you select an item on on the dropdownList the selected item value is inputted in the input box.

but every time i click submit i always shows this error

> AspNetCore._Views_DomesticWastes_Create_cshtml+d__25.MoveNext() in Create.cshtml
>   +
>               asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.LocationList, "LocName","LocName"))">

what should i do so that when i click submit it ignore the select and just add the data from input box?

thanks in advance guys! :)

Comment: Can you give us the Controller Code? Because the problem will not be in the View, but in the way that ViewBag.LocationList is filled.

Comment: List<Location> locationlist = new List<Location>();
            locationlist = (from location in _contextLoc.Locations
                            select location).ToList();
            ViewBag.LocationList = locationlist;

Comment: Can you post the 2 controller actions completely, the GET and the POST? I'm thinking that you are re-rendering your view for some reason, but that property isn't filled in correctly in the POST Action.

Comment: [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("DomWasId,DomWasLoc,DomWasDate,DomWasORNumber,DomWasName,DomWasAddress,DomWasContact,DomWasAccNo,DomWasCont,DomWasAmount,DomWasDataDate,DomWasDataUser,DomWasDataIpAdd")] DomesticWaste domesticWaste)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(domesticWaste);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(domesticWaste);
        }

Comment: That's where your problem is. I'm guessing your ModelState is invalid for some reason, so when you post the data, you hit the line where you return the View. But before returning the view, you didn't fill the ViewBag again. You View needs that property to be filled.

Comment: Try the following:
- Try filling the ViewBag.LocationList property again, just before the "return View(domesticWaste);" line, to see the error with the re-render disapper.
- Put a breakpoint on the ''if (ModelState.IsValid)" line, and check what is wrong with the ModelState.
- Investigate why the ModelState is invalid. I'm going to guess data binding between the post data and your model.

Comment: How did you implement dropdownlist selecteditem will be inputted into `input` box? I made a test with your current code, it did not achieve this. If you want `DomWasLoc` to be set from `DropDownList`, check my answer below. If it did not meet your requirement, you may edit your post to include the detail code to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Thanks.. ill's try

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to combine `input` and `select` for the same field `DomWasLoc`. You could bind the `DomWasLoc` directly to `select`.

A demo code like below:

```
            <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="DomWasLoc" class="control-label"></label>
            @*<input asp-for="DomWasLoc" class="form-control" />*@
            <select class="form-control"
                    asp-for="DomWasLoc"
                    asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.LocationList, "LocName","LocName"))">
                <option value="">- Select -</option>
            </select>
            <span asp-validation-for="DomWasLoc" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
```

Update:

Complte Code:
1. Model

```
    public class Location
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string LocName { get; set; }
}
public class DomesticWaste
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string DomWasLoc { get; set; }
}
```

2. Controller

   ```
   // GET: DomesticWastes/Create
   public IActionResult Create()
   {
       List<Location> locationlist = new List<Location>() {
           new Location{ Id = 1,  LocName = "L1" },
           new Location{ Id = 2,LocName = "L2" },
           new Location{ Id = 3,LocName = "L3" }
       };
       ViewBag.LocationList = locationlist;

       return View();
   }

   // POST: DomesticWastes/Create
   // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
   // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
   [HttpPost]
   [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
   public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,DomWasLoc")] DomesticWaste domesticWaste)
   {
       if (ModelState.IsValid)
       {
           _context.Add(domesticWaste);
           await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
           return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
       }
       return View(domesticWaste);
   }
   ```

Comment: yes i already try the but it is inserting the id of the selected item in the select not the string that i selected in the dropdown

Comment: Are you sure you test with this `asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.LocationList, "LocName","LocName"))"`? This line bind the `LocName` to `Select` value and it will pass the string instead of `Id`. Could you include your code in your original post?

Comment: hi.. my codes are in my lates post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51318273/insert-dropdownlist-selected-value-not-the-id-asp-net-core-2-0-enity-framework